# How do you convert a class component into a function? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use hooks in this function, but first I need to convert this class component into a function. I'm struggling to understand how render methods and constructors work in functions and could use some help understanding.

Class that I'm trying to convert:

```
class MainSwitchNavigator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { location, history } = this.props;

    this.previousLocation = location;
    navigator.setTopHistory(history);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <main>
        <div className={classes.container}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={OnboardingScreen} />
            <Route path="/consent" component={ConsentScreen} />
            <Route path="/privacy-policy" component={PrivacyPolicyScreen} />
            <Route path="/term-service" component={TermOfServiceScreen} />
            <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignInScreen} />
            <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUpScreen} />
            <Route path="/send-code" component={SendCodeScreen} />
            <Route path="/verify-code" component={VerifyCodeScreen} />
            <Route path="/new-password" component={NewPasswordScreen} />

            <Route path="/home" component={MasterContainer} />
            <Route path="/covid-testing-consent" component={CovidTestingConsentScreen} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
          <ToastContainer />
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

const NoMatch = ({ location }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>Page not found</h3>
  </div>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(MainSwitchNavigator);
```

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/five-ways-to-convert-react-class-components-to-functional-components-with-react-hooks gives a pretty sufficient explaination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind these:

- In a class, you need a constructor. In a function, the function by itself is the constructor.
- The function component receives the props as a parameter.
- In your function component you don't use the reserve key `this`.
- useEffect hook works as `componentDidMount` and `componentDidMethod` together.
- if you have a specific method (isn't in your code here but can apply in another) you can define this method as a function into the function component.

So, your code may be result in something like this:

```js
function MainSwitchNavigator({location, history, classes}) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        // this code was in your constructor, so I assume must be executed only once
        navigator.setTopHistory(history);
    }, []) // the empty array ensures the useEffect going to executes only one time.
    return (
        <main>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={OnboardingScreen}/>
                    <Route path="/consent" component={ConsentScreen}/>
                    <Route path="/privacy-policy" component={PrivacyPolicyScreen}/>
                    <Route path="/term-service" component={TermOfServiceScreen}/>
                    <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignInScreen}/>
                    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUpScreen}/>
                    <Route path="/send-code" component={SendCodeScreen}/>
                    <Route path="/verify-code" component={VerifyCodeScreen}/>
                    <Route path="/new-password" component={NewPasswordScreen}/>

                    <Route path="/home" component={MasterContainer}/>
                    <Route path="/covid-testing-consent" component={CovidTestingConsentScreen}/>
                    <Route component={NoMatch}/>
                </Switch>
                <ToastContainer/>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
    
}
```